# Polymorphic recursive calls in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, polymorphism

I've just discovered some very odd behavior in my program. I have a tree where every Node is a subclass of `Node`. I recursively calculate a bounding box by traversing the tree until I reach the unit primitives (i.e. a `Cube : Node`) at the leaf nodes.

The recursive function getBoundingBox() is declared as virtual and correctly traverses the tree. Leaf nodes override the function and return a unit cube.

However, when I trace the program it appears that the override has no effect on the recursive function getBoundingBox(), even though it works just fine for another function like getName().

**Example:**

```
class Node;

typedef shared_ptr<Node> node_ptr;

class Node
{
protected:
  vector<node_ptr> mChildren;
public:
  virtual string getName() { return "Node";}
  virtual BoundingBox getBoundingBox()
  {
    //Merge Bounding Boxes of Children
    BoundingBox bb = BoundingBox();
    //For each child
    for(vector<node_ptr>::iterator it = mChildren.begin(); it != mChildren.end(); ++it) {
      string name = (*it)->getName();//Correctly returns Node or Cube depending on type of (*it)
      bb = BoundingBox::Merge(bb, (*it)->getBoundingBox());//Always calls Node::getBoundingBox(); regardless of type
    }
    return bb;
  }
};

class Cube : public Node
{
public:
  virtual string getName() { return "Cube";}
  virtual BoundingBox getBoundingBox()
  {
    return BoundingBox::CreateUnitCube();
  }
};
```

Is there some sort of caveat about recursive polymorphism in c++ that I'm missing?

Comment: @Kyle C Added it to the code example

Comment: what does CreateUnitCube do?  Won't all of your cubes have exactly the same bounding box (i.e. you're not taking the position of the nodes into account)

Comment: When writing a function you expect to override something, you should get in the habit of declaring it with the override keyword. Catches alot of 'issues' with polymorphism.

Comment: Can you please modify you code so that it demonstrates the failure?

Comment: @Walter in the simplified case provided, no it will never need it. I designed it this way to avoid having to write a specific edge case for every primitive type that I might find at the ends. I suppose I could make Node a purely virtual class and encapsulate that in a subclass called NodeGroup or something.

Comment: Why does `Cube` inherit from `Node` and not the other way around? AFAIKS, `Cube` doesn't need `mChildren`.

Comment: @Walter because not all Nodes are Cubes. This is a simplified example but Nodes can also be Cylinders Spheres and other primatives

Comment: @benjymous All cubes in this example will have the same bounding box because I simplified the problem. In my full code I also apply transformations to the bounding box. Each node has an associated Homogeneous transform

Comment: There is no reason the above code shouldn't call Cube::getBoundingBox if it is calling Cube::getName. It appears that you may not be providing the actual code, though, because you have to keep fixing things, so I would suggest posting the actual code. Also, if you haven't already, make certain that Cube::getBoundingBox is in fact not being called, by placing a breakpoint in Cube::getBoundingBox. Don't base it off of what is returned.

Comment: @Kindread I wasn't sure how to use the override syntax with c++ (I'm used to Java so putting it after the declaration never occurred to me). Turns out that highlighted my problem. I hadn't declared getBoundingBox() virtual like I thought I had. Didn't think anything of it because it compiled.

Comment: There is no special caveat.  I compiled the code as you present it here; adding headers and the like and it does what you expect; i.e., the bounding box is correctly computed.  Maybe you have edited it? If you are still having a problem, it would help if you give as an example, a complete program which minimally (include nothing that is not immediately relavent) demonstrates the issue as part of it's output.

Answer (score 1):

I think your inheritance structure is muddled up. It makes more sense to have a base class `Node` which may be abstract

```
class BaseNode {
public:
  virtual BoundingBox getBoundingBox() const = 0;
};
```

and then define the different types of nodes

```
using node_ptr = std::shared_ptr<BaseNode>;
class Node : public BaseNode
{
  std::vector<node_ptr> mChildren;
public:
  BoundingBox getBoundingBox() const noexcept
  {
    BoundingBox bb;
    for(auto pc:mChildren)
      bb.merge(pc->getBoundingBox());
    return bb;
  }
};

class Cube : public BaseNode
{
public:
  BoundingBox getBoundingBox() const noexcept
  { return BoundingBox::CreateUnitCube(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cube` isn't a `Node` as you didn't use public inheritance.

I'm not sure how your actual code even compiles, but try to change it to:

```
class Cube : public Node
```

Comment: Technically the default inheritance on a class is private, and public on a struct (the 'other' difference between a a struct and a class)

Comment: this should affect `getName()` in the same way.